# Is it possible to say: "asked and answered about"?

Tags: prepositions, usage

I'm explaining how to play a game and there's a part I'm not sure if it's ok or not. Can you say the following?:

"...everyone will be sitting in a semicircle, (each end will receive an object) and they must ask and answer the same thing (about the object given), coming back to the beginning (of the semicircle) with the question (about the object) and returning with the answer through each student up to the last one who asked...it'll get to a point in which both objects **are being asked and answered about** and students are confused about who's asking what and answering whom and so on...

Comment: No, you can't do that. If you've got two verbs and they either take different prepositions or one verb needs a preposition and the other doesn't, you must explicitly put each preposition immediately after the verb it goes with. Syntactically, it would be fine to write *both objects are being **answered and asked about...*** - but that version is "awkward" because asking naturally precedes answering in the real world. So you have to write *both objects are being **asked about** and answered...*

Comment: *Sometimes* if the two verbs take different prepositions, people discard the first preposition entirely in such context (for example, *Data can be imported and exported **from** the application*, discarding ***to*** after ***imported***). But you might lose points for doing that in an exam.

Comment: maybe asked about and answered to? But to me it seems awkward as well...

Comment: No, it's not idiomatic in English to say a question was *answered **to***. That preposition works in the context of an adjectival modifier of the noun, ***in answer to** the question*, but we rarely use it after the *verb* (even if it attaches to the *object*, as in *"Yes", I answered [**to**] him*). Stick with *both objects are being **asked about and answered...*** as per my first comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did in the end. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is wrong.

Because the *object* may be "asked about", but it is the *questions* that will be answered. You don't answer an object.

An alternative might be to say:

> It will reach a point where questions are being asked and answered about both objects

Comment: The OP asked about *answering **about** an object*, not *answering an object*. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @gotube You answer a question. You don't answer "about" a question. But I didn't bother addressing that mistake because it is a moot point. Removing the word "about" wouldn't correct the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that grammar is correct, a native speaker might say it, and it is easy to understand. However, it is a bit awkward.

Here's a natural usage of "answer about something":

> Allan: What are the impacts of this policy on local education and real estate values?
> Betty: That's an excellent question. I'll **answer about education**, but I'll let another panellist **answer about real estate values**.

In this context, and in yours, it's understood that the direct object of "answer" is the question, and the "about..." specifies what the topic or aspect of the question.

THAT SAID, Astralbee's suggested alternative is clear, natural, and not at all awkward.