# Transitive and intransitive verbs, parallelism and object

Tags: verbs, objects, parallelism, intransitive

```
This is my second question marked to be closed. If I knew the language very well, I wouldn't ask any questions here. I removed the original question. Let the moderators write the question here the way they want!
```

Comment: to ***confirm*** and to ***inform*** are completely different verbs, so you should choose the one that matches your intended sense. But note that *they couldn't have confirmed to the patient* isn't idiomatic without explicitly specifying ***what*** is being confirmed: *they couldn't have **confirmed the diagnosis** to the patient*.

Comment: I am aware that those are different verbs. Assume that ellipsis has been applied: **confirmed [the disease] to the patient** and **informed the patient [about the disease].**

Comment: I don't think either ellipsis sounds natural.

Comment: I can't think of a time when I would use "confirmed" with the preposition "to." I would say "they couldn't have confirmed with the patient."

Comment: I also think that having both verbs is redundant and feels awkward. The meaning here is "the doctor told the patient the diagnosis and discussed options." and both "informed" and "confirmed" can include that meaning, although each has slightly different connotations. I would pick one and only use that.

Comment: I might have used a wrong example here. I couldn't come up with a better example right now. I just want to know how parallelism would work with intransitive verb and  transitive verb if both use the same object, one directly and the other with the help of a proposition.

Comment: Perhaps [Is it possible to say: "asked and answered about"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342587/is-it-possible-to-say-asked-and-answered-about) addresses what you're asking about here. You seem to be just asking about using multiple verbs where not all of them accept the same preposition (where "parallelism" doesn't work! :)

Comment: To be clear, is your question about how to join an intransitive and a transitive verb with the same object?

Comment: @gotube yes. The example I wrote is non standard. I couldn't get good one yet.  What about "You can either **stand up for the fighters** or **oppose the fighters**" ? Can it be simplified to **1.** You can either **stand up for** or **oppose** the fighters. **2.** You can either **oppose** or  **stand up for** the fighters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it seems that example is somehow related to my question but in which both verbs use propositions to connect with object - not a transitive-and-intransitive question.

Comment: @all One of the problems I found in this forum is that it is very difficult to understand questions. I often leave this forum and look out for the answer somewhere else without even able to determine the questions I saw here are related to my question or not. May be because the questions are too specific and too descriptive to connect with my question. I am familiar with stackoverflow and I have never noticed such an issue there.

Comment: When an intransitive verb is used with an object, the two are joined by a ***preposition***, not a ***proposition***. But I think you're confusing the issue by bringing up transitive/intransitive verbs in this context. So far as I can see, the ***only*** thing that matters here is that you're concatenating two verbs ***that take different prepositions*** into a single construction (both verbs sharing the same object, for example). It just so happens that in your *specific* examples, one of the verbs takes a "null preposition" (because it's transitive).

Comment: ...also note that ***to confirm*** and ***to inform*** are in fact both transitive. But the default object of ***confirm*** is a ***diagnosis, hypothesis***, whereas the default object of ***inform*** is ***a person who is being given some information*** (perhaps a diagnosis, perhaps just the time of day).

Comment: @FumbleFingers my bad, I was using proposition instead of preposition. My question is risen from my misunderstanding of the verb confirm. Just leave that example and consider it as a question of transitive-and-intransitive verb as I explained in the first comment i wrote today.

Comment: @SouthIndianɪŋɡlɪʃɪfaɪd Great. I've added that info into your question. This other example you've suggested is much better because it makes logical sense. A problem with it though is that "stand up for" is a three-word phrasal verb, not an intransitive verb followed by a preposition. I've now answered your question.

Comment: @gotube Thanks for the remark. It is better to have a proper example to ask this question, but I couldn't come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The grammar** of your sentences 1 and 2 are correct and natural and have the same function. They're interchangeable.

The **meaning** of the sentences is a bit odd because if the patient already knows the information, you cannot inform them, and if they don't know it, you can't confirm with them.

But I understand your question clearly enough and hope I've answered it.